# Is there a way to change the claim used to set IssuedAt/ValidFrom/ValidTo with JwtSecurityTokenHandler?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, adobe, identity

I am trying to use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to parse a JWT from AdobeIO. They don't appear to use standard claims, so the `IssuedAt` property resulting parsed `JwtSecurityToken` is just a default `DateTime`.

Is there a way to change how this token is parsed so I can have proper working `IssuedAt`/`ValidFrom`/`ValidTo`?

I tried using `InboundClaimMap`/`OutboundClaimMap` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

It seems they use `created_at` instead of `iat` and `expires_in` instead of `exp`.

Comment: What claim do they use for `exp` instead?

Comment: They have a `created_at` and `expires_in`.

Comment: Can you not parse the JWT, read those claims, and validate the date manually?

Comment: I can, and I am going to do so now, but I wanted to know if it could be done with JwtSecurityTokenHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. It appears that it's [hardcoded to `exp` claim](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/JsonWebToken.cs#L309-L313).

```cs
public class JsonWebToken : SecurityToken
{
    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the 'value' of the 'exp' claim { exp, 'value' } converted to a <see cref="DateTime"/> assuming 'value' is seconds since UnixEpoch (UTC 1970-01-01T0:0:0Z).
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>If the 'exp' claim is not found, then <see cref="DateTime.MinValue"/> is returned.</remarks>
    public override DateTime ValidTo => JwtTokenUtilities.GetDateTime(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, Payload);
```